# ¿Existe un verbo en español que signifique "partir por la mitad" o "dividir en dos partes iguales"?

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras, verbos, significado

Por casualidad hoy me he topado con el verbo inglés *[to halve](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/halve)*, el cual significa:

> to divide (something) into two equal parts
>
> to reduce (something) to one half of the original amount or size

La acepción que me interesa es la primera, y es que de repente no se me ocurría ningún verbo que por sí solo significase lo mismo, ya que la traducción suele ser *dividir por la mitad* o *en mitades*.

Lo primero que se me ocurrió fue "[mediar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OkLUJV6)", pero esta palabra, a juzgar por todas sus acepciones, significa en general "llegar a la mitad" o "ponerse en la mitad" o "en medio".

Así pues, ¿qué verbo existe en español con el significado de *to halve*?

Curiosidad: si en vez de en dos partes se quiere dividir en tres, se puede usar el verbo *[terciar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZXJkWzK)* ("dividir algo en tres partes").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buscando en el [DIRAE](http://dirae.es/), encontré dos opciones. La primera es un verbo conocido con una acepción inesperada:

> **[promediar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ULKspl3)**
>
> 1. tr. Repartir algo en dos partes iguales o casi iguales.

Y la segunda es mi preferida, aunque es una opción poco usada:

> **[demediar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C8z3Uhh)**
>
> De *de-* y *mediar*.
>
> 1. tr. p. us. Partir, dividir en mitades. U. t. c. intr.

Y siguiendo con el número de partes, para cuatro partes se puede usar *[cuartear](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BT17HLh)* ("partir o dividir algo en cuartas partes").

Comment: Aunque no está en el DLE, yo he oído sobre todo en contextos técnicos "bipartir". Se deriva naturalmente de bipartito o de [bipartición](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5a1kxFE) que sí están.

Comment: Una opción indudablemente exacta pero que, según indica el DRAE, se limitaría al ámbito de la geometría, es [bisecar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5beotLo): "Dividir en dos partes iguales". Se podría bisecar (por medio de una [bisectriz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5bftRVt)) un ángulo o un cuadrado, por ejemplo.

Comment: @Rafael, tampoco en el DLE, pero que he oíd en contextos técnicos: "equipartir".  Por cierto, existe en Portugués: Verbo Eqüipartir.